# Create a user in MongoDb using powershell

Tags: mongodb, powershell

I'm using MongoDb v3.0.3 and want to create a user in a database with admin privileges using powershell. I hook into the C# driver but I don't get very far:

```
$pathToMongoDbCSharpDriver = "F:\Work\...\mongocsharpdriver.1.9.2\lib\net35"
Add-Type -Path "$pathToMongoDbCSharpDriver\MongoDB.Bson.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$pathToMongoDbCSharpDriver\MongoDB.Driver.dll"
$client = New-Object -TypeName MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient -ArgumentList "mongodb://localhost:30000"
$server = $client.GetServer()

$databaseName = "Dev"
$collectionName = "Settings"
$database = $server.GetDatabase($databaseName)
$collection = $database.GetCollection($collectionName)

$credentials = New-Object -TypeName MongoDB.Driver.MongoCredential("Admin", "password", $true);
$user = New-Object -TypeName MongoDB.Driver.MongoUser($credentials, $false)
```

$credentials fails because argument 1 it is not a MongoIdentity and I can't find any information about how to create one of these. Any help would be gratefully received

Comment: maybe it would be easier to just call `mongo` and pass some javascript code to it.

Comment: That had occurred to me.... I'll see if there is an answer that uses the api provided first

Answer (score 0):

I use all the parameters in the argument list. The following works fine for me:

```
$Client = New-Object -TypeName MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient -ArgumentList "mongodb://dbuser:dbpass@localhost:27017/test"
```